# How do I change a 500 error into a 404 error and show a custom page?

Tags: html, apache, http

I just launched a site and when I go to a non-existing page, I get a 500 Internal Server error instead of a 404 errror.

I was thinking that this was because I didn't have a 404.html page (just a guess), but I just created a 404.html page at the root and I still get 500 errors.

What should I do to make it so that when somebody types in a bad address they get redirected to my custom 404 error page?

There is no special stuff going on with my site, just HTML, CSS and a tiny bit of javaScript. Not a Rails app, not a Wordpress site, no PHP, etc. ..just HTML files on an Apache server.

The error I get when I go to a non-existing page or directory reads like this"

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   webmaster@subdomain.domain.com and inform them of the time the
>   error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused
>   the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Step 1: Figure out *why* you are getting a 500. Don't guess. Read the error logs.

Comment: @Quentin I'm getting a 500 because the page doesn't exist.

Comment: No, you aren't. The standard Apache behaviour when a file is missing is to report a 404. There has to be some other factor at play in addition to the file not existing.

Comment: How can I figure that out?

Comment: Reading the error logs is usually a good starting point.

Comment: Sorry, where will I find the error logs?

Comment: @Quentin can I maybe see this by using console in the Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: I don't know where your install of Apache is configured to store the error logs. **internal server** errors are not reported to the client, so they won't appear in Chrome Dev tools.

Comment: The error you quoted in your edit is just the standard "There was a 500 error" that gets reported to the client. You need to look in the server's error logs to find out what the real error is. They aren't reported to the client (as they might contain sensitive information).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to find those.

Comment: I found the error log on my server but it's blank.

Comment: just sent a question to my ISP. Thanks for the suggestions @Quentin

Comment: Can you debug the website?

Answer (score 1):

After you have the Error 500 problem solved you can create a custom 404 page by editing your .htaccess file you should have one in the root of your directory. 
Open the file with a text editor and add this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yourwebsite.com/404page.html
```

You could also create a custom Error 500 by changing the above code to suite your needs.

It's pretty self explanatory but the last part is the directory that users will be directed to after they receive a 404 error.

Comment: For some reason, I never saw this reply. The problem seems to have fixed itself, but the site isn't directing to my custom 404 page, so I'll give this a shot. Thanks!